# Why might you NOT observe a tradeoff between two life-history traits?

Tags: life-history

I have traditionally thought of and heard about life-history traits (e.g., size at first reproduction, number of offspring, size of offspring, survival, etc., etc.) as drawing from a finite pool of resources that an organism has, and therefore exhibiting tradeoffs. So, for instance, an organism that invests in a lot of offspring would experience a decreased probability of survival.

It has recently come to my attention that this is not always the case, and I'm not sure why. I have been directed to the work of David Houle, who wrote extensively on the topic of life-history traits, but some of his work is inaccessible to me intellectually. I was hoping that somebody had a more digestible explanation or was maybe more familiar with Houle's work.

Comment: Could you link to a few works in particular, or where you first read that?

Comment: The name of the paper I've read is, "Genetic covariance of fitness correlates: what genetic correlations are made of and why it matters". David Houle from the journal Evolution, 1991, Vol. 45. Issue 3. Pp 630-648.

Comment: It apparently has something to do with the number of loci influencing ability to obtain resources versus the number of loci influencing how those resources are allocated...

Comment: For those willing to answer: [Here is David Houle's article](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2409916?uid=3737760&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21103597650137)

Answer (score 1):

The simple explanation is that there are three (or more) traits drawing from the pool, and you're only looking for trade-offs between two of them. The unobserved third may show the effect of a trade-off.

Comment: Can you explain some more with references?